# Why do my results differ using the same weights and same network?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, yolov5

I want to use YOLOv5 pre-trained layer weights as part of a multi-task network. For this I saved the state_dict, loaded my custom model and overwrote the object detection layers (see below). Simply calling `model.load_state_dict` does not work, since I named my model layers differently. For inference I use a custom detect module.

Problem: Although I use **exactly the same weights and input**, the results are very different:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0b8q.jpg

**I compared some of the intermediate results from different layers and noticed that they drift apart the further the data move through the network**.
It seems like the error is due to rounding but both models and input are 32bit.

This is how I saved the original state_dict: In detect.py just before the inference part in the yolov5 project:

```
torch.save(model.model.state_dict(), 'yolov5m_state_dict.pt')
```

And in my own project using a different environment I define my model like so (the other task heads have been omitted):

```
class YOLOPointMFull(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, inp_ch=3, nc=80, anchors=anchors):
    super(YOLOPointMFull, self).__init__()

    # CSPNet Backbone
    self.Conv1 = Conv(inp_ch, 48, 6, 2, 2)   # ch_in, ch_out, kernel, stride, padding, groups
    self.Conv2 = Conv(48, 96, 3, 2)
    self.Bottleneck1 = C3(96, 96, 2)    # ch_in, ch_out, number
    self.Conv3 = Conv(96, 192, 3, 2)
    self.Bottleneck2 = C3(192, 192, 4)
    self.Conv4 = Conv(192, 384, 3, 2)
    self.Bottleneck3 = C3(384, 384, 6)
    self.Conv5 = Conv(384, 768, 3, 2)
    self.Bottleneck4 = C3(768, 768, 2)
    self.SPPooling = SPPF(768, 768, 5)

    # Object Detector Head
    self.Conv6 = Conv(768, 384, 1, 1, 0)
    # ups, cat
    self.Bottleneck5 = C3(768, 384, 2)
    self.Conv7 = Conv(384, 192, 1, 1, 0)
    # ups, cat
    self.Bottleneck6 = C3(384, 192, 2)  # --> detect
    self.Conv8 = Conv(192, 192, 3, 2, 1)
    # cat
    self.Bottleneck7 = C3(384, 384, 2)  # --> detect
    self.Conv9 = Conv(384, 384, 3, 2, 1)
    # cat
    self.Bottleneck8 = C3(768, 768, 2)  # --> detect
    self.Detect = Detect(nc, anchors=anchors, ch=(192, 384, 768))

    self.ups = nn.Upsample(scale_factor=(2, 2), mode='nearest')

def forward(self, x):
    # Backbone
    x = self.Conv1(x)
    x = self.Conv2(x)   # check
    x = self.Bottleneck1(x)
    x = self.Conv3(x)
    xb = self.Bottleneck2(x)
    x = self.Conv4(xb)
    xc = self.Bottleneck3(x)
    x = self.Conv5(xc)
    x = self.Bottleneck4(x)
    x = self.SPPooling(x)

    # Object Detector Head
    xd = self.Conv6(x)
    x = self.ups(xd)
    x = torch.cat((x, xc), dim=1)
    x = self.Bottleneck5(x)
    xe = self.Conv7(x)
    x = self.ups(xe)
    x = torch.cat((x, xb), dim=1)
    xf = self.Bottleneck6(x)
    x = self.Conv8(xf)
    x = torch.cat((x, xe), dim=1)
    xg = self.Bottleneck7(x)
    x = self.Conv9(xg)
    x = torch.cat((x, xd), dim=1)
    x = self.Bottleneck8(x)
    x = self.Detect([xf, xg, x])

    return x
```

With this method I overwrote the weights of the network to work around the fact that both state_dicts have different keys:

```
yolo_sd = torch.load('yolov5m.pt')

# load model with default anchors, input channels and classes
model = load_model('Model')

yp_full_sd = model.state_dict()

def load_pretrained(target, source):
    print(len(target), len(source))
    for i, (tk, sk) in enumerate(zip(target, source)):
        layer_target = tk.split('.')[-1]
        layer_source = sk.split('.')[-1]
        if layer_source == layer_target and source[sk].shape == target[tk].shape:
            target[tk] = source[sk]
        else:
            print(f'Failed to overwrite {tk}')
    return target

yp_full_sd = load_pretrained(yp_full_sd, yolo_sd)

torch.save({"model_state_dict": yp_full_sd,}, 'logs/full_model/yolo_pure.pt')
```

Here are some things that I have already checked / additional info:

- confirmed that the input is exactly the same (RGB, dimensions, float32, pixel values), no further preprocessing
- saved weights in different formats (.pt, .pth.tar) with same result
- the state_dict was from the unfused yolo model (i.e. BN and Conv layers are separate)
- the model is set to eval mode during inference
- both models ran on the same gpu
- the non-maximum suppression parameters are the same
- my conda project environment uses: torch 1.11.0, pytorch 1.12.1 (why do I have both?) python 3.8.13, numpy 1.23.1, opencv-python 4.5.5.64
- my conda yolov5 environment uses: torch 1.10.0+cu113, python 3.8.0, opencv-python 4.5.4.58

Edit:
While trying to create a minimal reproducible example by using `torch.ones(1, 3, 256, 256, dtype=torch.float)` as input I was able to narrow down the error: The output in fact only begins to diverge after the first C3 module ([see YOLOv5 architecture](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/6998)) or to be more exact, after (both of) the Conv<s>BNSiLU</s> layers of the C3 module.
The mean absolute difference of the tensors when they first diverge is just 9.7185235e-05 which is small enough to be a rounding error.
To double-check, I confirmed that the weights of the Conv layers of either implementation are exactly the same.
Below is a screenshot of the top left corner of the first layer of the output difference if that helps:
[image]

Comment: so... you have different _implementations_ of the inference calculations? yeah, sure, numerics can mess things up. I wouldn't expect serious _divergence_ however, just some error propagation, but neural networks are supposed to not be too sensitive to numerical inaccuracies -- can you demonstrate for a terribly simple dense or conv2d (3x3) layer how the same input leads to different outputs, given terribly simple input (3x3 matrix of values, similar for weights)?

Comment: Yes, different implementations. I added some more info to my post in case it helps, but a minimal reproducible example is kind of hard to make.